# How can I open files externally in Emacs dired mode?

Tags: emacs, dired, docview

I want to open a pdf with evince instead of DocView mode. Is there a possibility to open a file with a specific command like 'evince'?

Answer (score 39):

Yes. Use `!` while in dired to run a shell command on a file.

In the case of `evince`, it's smarter to use `&`, though, which will run the command asynchronously, so emacs will still be usable while you have the PDF open.

Comment: Note that you can customize the default command used by `!` via `dired-guess-shell-alist-user` from `dired-x`: `(setq dired-guess-shell-alist-user '(("\\.pdf\\'" "evince")))`

Comment: i wish i have read through before I tried it. :-) appending & in the end works well

Answer (score 21):

There is more then one way to do that. I suggest [OpenWith](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OpenWith) library. Setup for your case may look like that:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/downloaded/openwith.el")
(require 'openwith)
(setq openwith-associations '(("\\.pdf\\'" "evince" (file))))
(openwith-mode t)
```

It sets file handler that will work from both `dired` and `find-file`.

Comment: At least in Mac OSX, I replaced `evince` with `open`, and then it uses the default software (`Skim` in my case).

Comment: Note that in this case you would just hit `RET` on the file name in dired instead of using `!` or `&` to run a shell command.  You also lose all the built in associations by using setq on openwith-associations.  Might there be a better way to change only the pdf association while leaving in associations for .mp3, .jpg, ... ?

Comment: Yes, there is an easy way to change the pdf association without losing the others:  M-x customize-group RET openwith RET

Comment: In my OS 10.11, after substituting  `evince`  with `open`, PDF files are opened by Preview.

Answer (score 11):

Try this.

```
(defun dired-open-file ()
  "In dired, open the file named on this line."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((file (dired-get-filename nil t)))
    (message "Opening %s..." file)
    (call-process "gnome-open" nil 0 nil file)
    (message "Opening %s done" file)))
```

Comment: This worked nicely. I replace `gnome-open` with `xdg-open`, in case of use in another GUI such as KDE.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `!` to open the file and then specify a command.

Comment: And `&` instead of `!` if you want to run that command asynchronously.

Answer (score 6):

Note that you can keep the process alive after exiting Emacs by using [`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) [Wikipedia], so put the point on a single file in `dired`:

```
C-u ! nohup evince ? &
```

which creates a [Persistent Processes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PersistentProcesses) [EmacsWiki].

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, I offen use ! and command "explorer" to open PDF/Word/Excel...

Answer (score 1):

Another windows OS solution using `explorer.exe` to open single/multiple files. To open multiple files, mark the file using `m` in `dired` and then hit `o` to open multiple files. To just open a single file under point hit `o`. I have tested it in Emacs 28.2 GUI running natively on windows (no WSL/Cygwin/Linux-on-Windows).

```
  (use-package dired
      :bind (:map dired-mode-map
          ("o" . jr/dired-open))
      :config
      (defun jr/dired-open ()
      (interactive)
      (if-let ((marks (dired-get-marked-files)))
        (dolist (file marks)
          (shell-command (format "explorer.exe %s" (file-name-nondirectory file))))
      (user-error "No marked files; aborting"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun dired-open()
  (interactive)
  (setq file (dired-get-file-for-visit))
  (setq ext (file-name-extension file))
  (cond ((string= ext "pdf")
         ;; shell-quote-argument escapes white spaces on the file name
         (async-shell-command (concat "zathura " (shell-quote-argument file))))
        ((string= ext "epub")
         (async-shell-command (concat "zathura " (shell-quote-argument file))))
        ((string= ext "rar")
         (async-shell-command (concat "file-roller " (shell-quote-argument file))))
        ((string= ext "zip")
         (async-shell-command (concat "file-roller " (shell-quote-argument file))))
        (t (dired-find-file))))
```